# Xlabels does not show up using subplot2grid - matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, jupyter

My problem stands with matplotlib and more precisely with subplot2grid : xlabels just refuse to show up on the 2 first bar-charts (following screen cap.)

[image: xlabels refuse to show]
**

### code below :

**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,15), dpi=1600) 

fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(0,0))
t_mois.sort('mois').plot(kind='bar', x='mois', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax1, alpha=alpha_bar_chart)
ax1.set_xlabel('plot 1 x-label')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(0,1))
t_semaine.sort('jours_semaine').plot(kind='bar', x='jours_semaine', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax2, alpha=alpha_bar_chart)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
ax2.set_xlabel('plot 2 x-label')

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(1,0), colspan=2)
t_jours_mois.sort('jours_mois').plot(kind='bar', x='jours_mois', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax3)

ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(2,0), colspan=2)
t_jour_annee.sort('jours_annee').plot(kind='bar', x='jours_annee', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax4)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have already tried several things (e.g change gridsize, set them manually, add spaces between plots...) without success. By contrast, when I plot it in a seperate grid or in the console, xlabels show up naturally.

Any guess ?

Many thanks

N-B : I'm using Jupyter (latest version of Ipython Notebook) with a Python 3 kernel.

Comment: Maybe a bug in an old matplotlib version? I could not reproduce it with matplotlib version 2.0.0.